# Validate a field date value in a node, only if there isn't a Google Calendar Event in my public calendar for that day

Tags: 7, datetime

I need to validate a date value only if there is not created an event for that specific date in my public google calendar.

I have found a field validation project (https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation) where I can type php to validate a field. What php do I type please to do this?
Thanks